# Django: Using a deleted/discarded field en lieu of deleting a database row - What to do with related models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Person( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    discarded = models.BooleanField( default=False )

class Thing( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    discarded = models.BooleanField( default=False )
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey( Person, blank=True, null=True, related_name="things" )
```

Instead of deleting items in the database, I would prefer to set the item's 'discarded' field to True so that a history of that item can be saved and it can be restored if necessary. However, I would also like the model's relationships to reflect that change:

```
key = Thing.objects.create(name="key")
phone = Thing.objects.create(name="phone")
hat = Thing.objects.create(name="hat")

sally = Person.objects.create(name="sally")
sally.things.add(key)
sally.things.add(phone)
sally.things.add(hat)

sally.things.all()
[<Thing name="key">,<Thing name="phone">,<Thing name="hat">]

phone.discarded = True
phone.save()

sally.things.all()
[<Thing name="key">,<Thing name="hat">]
```

Essentially, I want the 'things' queryset to inherently reflect the value of each of its items' discarded fields. I am NOT looking for this answer:

```
sally.things.exclude(discarded=True) #NO!
```

The sql would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
Thing t
LEFT JOIN Person p ON t.belongs_to = p.id AND t.discarded != 1
WHERE p.name="sally"
```

I've checked out the documentation for the [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) option but it appears to only limit choices made available in a Django form for the model. It doesn't seem that it would enforce constraints on existing model relationships.

I have lots of models with lots of relationships that I would like to use this 'discarded' field technique on. Are there any Django solutions out there?

Comment: I'm really not sure but does this help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom  manager for `Thing` and override its `get_queryset` method to exclude all discarded items:

```
class ThingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ThingManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(discarded=True)
```

And update your `Thing` model:

```
class Thing( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    discarded = models.BooleanField( default=False )
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey( Person, blank=True, null=True, related_name="things" )

    objects = ThingManager()
```

Your queries on model `Thing` will henceforth exclude discarded items

Comment: oh right - model managers - I forgot that I can customize querysets and use multiple managers on a single model... (still learning django, obviously.) Perfect.